# How to convert fastq to uBAM with picard dock on google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-genomics, picard

I have been trying to convert my fastq files on google cloud to uBAM files but no success so far. Here is code I used:

```
dsub \
--project projectID \
--zones "us-central1-*" \
--logging gs://bucket/logging \
--image broadinstitute/picard \
--command 'java -Xmx8G -jar picard.jar FastqToSam FASTQ=gs://bucket/S_1.fq FASTQ2=gs://bucket/S_2.fq OUTPUT=gs://bucket/S_fastqtosam.bam READ_GROUP_NAME=Cancers SAMPLE_NAME=TS LIBRARY_NAME=Solexa-272222 PLATFORM_UNIT=CL100056 PLATFORM=illumina SEQUENCING_CENTER=BI RUN_DATE=2017-08-20T00:00:00-0400'
--wait
```

I can see the image has been pulled and run successful, but then I got the error message saying the command is incorrect, and please check PicardcommandLine -h

Does anyone have experience in converting fastq to uBAM with google cloud? PLease help. Much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `broadinstitute/picard` docker image already runs java as its Entrypoint (see [1] for more details). You need to change the command to remove `java -Xmx8G -jar picard.jar`.

I'm also not sure whether passing cloud storage paths directly to picard would work and you likely need to specify additional arguments (`--input` and `--output`) when running dsub. See https://github.com/DataBiosphere/dsub/blob/master/docs/input_output.md for more details.

[1] The [Entrypoint](https://hub.docker.com/r/broadinstitute/picard/~/dockerfile/) is defined as `"/usr/picard/docker_helper.sh"`, which is this [file](https://github.com/broadinstitute/picard/blob/master/src/main/resources/picard/docker_helper.sh) that runs java directly. Each docker image has its own Entrypoint, so it's important to ensure you are using the right commands for each docker image.